# XCTest. Detecting access gallery alert view

Tags: ios, swift2, uialertview, ios-ui-automation, xctest

I have a problem with detecting UIAlertView which appear when I wont to get photo from photo gallery in UI XCTest. My code:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let alertView = app.alerts["\u{201c}MyAppName\u{201d} Would Like to Access Your Photos"]
```

Alert view is already on screen but in `alertView` I got nil. Anybody knows how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some charters in alertView Value is miss.

use index instead String Value.

```
 let alertView = app.alerts.elementBoundByIndex(0)
```

and example for tap alertButton

```
 app.alerts.elementBoundByIndex(0).buttons["OK"].tap()
```

it works for me

Comment: Generally it works. But now became another problem. After clicking OK button I get error "No matches found for Alert". It's strange because actually button was pressed.